# Setting DTR-line with (one) batch file

Tags: serial-port, dtr

To enable/disable the comport DTR control line I have to use a batchfile.

What works, is to open the ComPort and/or to enable/disable the DTR-Line. But the big problem is, with each new call of the batch file the comport is closed again because the previous instance is not longer valid anymore.

Better would be such approach:

Call batch file A to open ComPort
Call batch file B to enable DTR-line or call batch file A again with a different parameter to enable DTR-Line
Call batch file B to disable DTR-Line
etc..
Question: How can I solve the problem with a batch script in order to enable/disable the DTR-line?

Thanks